# RCPTT mvn clean package error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

```
[INFO] Building zip: /prj/iceng/qsip1/workspaces/c_jrex/RCPTT/workspace_rcptt/FM_New/target/projectName-productTests-1.5.5-SNAPSHOT-result.zip
[DEBUG] adding directory rcptt/
[DEBUG] adding entry rcptt/stdout.txt
[DEBUG] adding entry rcptt/stderr.txt
[DEBUG] adding entry rcptt/log.txt
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 05:26 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-02T02:41:21-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/121M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.xored.ci4rcptt:ci4rcptt-maven-plugin:1.5.4:package (default-package) on project productTests: Could not read test results file /prj/iceng/qsip1/workspaces/c_jrex/RCPTT/workspace_rcptt/FM_New/target/surefire-reports/TEST-productTests.junit.xml -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.xored.ci4rcptt:ci4rcptt-maven-plugin:1.5.4:package (default-package) on project productTests: Could not read test results file /prj/iceng/qsip1/workspaces/c_jrex/RCPTT/workspace_rcptt/FM_New/target/surefire-reports/TEST-productTests.junit.xml
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Could not read test results file /prj/iceng/qsip1/workspaces/c_jrex/RCPTT/workspace_rcptt/FM_New/target/surefire-reports/TEST-productTests.junit.xml
    at com.xored.q7.maven.PackageMojo.readError(PackageMojo.java:109)
    at com.xored.q7.maven.PackageMojo.failBuildIfFailingTests(PackageMojo.java:56)
    at com.xored.q7.maven.PackageMojo.execute(PackageMojo.java:47)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I think the issue is Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: `Could not read test results file /prj/iceng/qsip1/workspaces/c_jrex/RCPTT/workspace_rcptt/FM_New/target/surefire-reports/TEST-productTests.junit.xml`

surefire-reports/TEST-productTests.junit.xml is not generated. Why is that?

It has not produced anything inside surefire-reports directory. See here:

```
vl-c-jrex-ice{114}> ls
projectName-productTests-1.5.5-SNAPSHOT-result.zip projects/ results/ runner/ runner-workspace/ surefire-reports/
vl-c-jrex-ice{115}> pwd
/prj/iceng/qsip1/workspaces/c_jrex/RCPTT/workspace_rcptt/FM_New/target
vl-c-jrex-ice{117}> ls surefire-reports/ -a
./ ../
vl-c-jrex-ice{118}>
```

I did mvn package install as given in https://ci.xored.com/doc/ci4rcptt-maven-plugin/

A solution is given here: [maven-surefire-report-plugin not generating surefire-report.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387052/maven-surefire-report-plugin-not-generating-surefire-report-html) 
but it did not work . Any suggestions?

```
Full Log: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=getfile&id=21446& 
pom.xml : https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=getfile&id=21447&
Eclipse Forum Link: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1691342/
```

Comment: Check if the user the JVM runs on actually has write access for the relevant dirs

Comment: I am running mvn from my user and all have -rw-rw-r-- for my user. Hence It has read write permission. @Dragondraikk

Comment: The problem is that the plugin defines it's own life cycle but i don't know where surefire is bound to. Based on the log files it does not look like it's bound...so there couldn't be any reports generated...